# Apache error "Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting." No PHP or MySQL

Tags: java, apache, jboss, apache2, mod-jk

I'm running Apache 2.2.14 on Windows Server 2003, without PHP or MySQL, basically to proxy as a web server for a Java web app. Every few hours or so Apache restarts with a message `[notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.`

This (or very similar) issue seems to be most common for Apache/PHP/MySQL combinations, where the solution is to copy a couple of .dll's into system32 directory (e.g., [Apache error [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138269/apache-error-notice-parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477-rest)).

However, in this case there's no PHP or MySQL involved, so I'm wondering what other causes for `status 3221225477` restarts could be.

Appreciate your insight.