# SimpleSamlPHP makes Apache crash on PHP 5.3.9

Tags: php, apache, easyphp

I run [simpleSamlPHP 1.9](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.9/) on a PHP 5.3.9 installation in EasyPHP, on a Windows XP machine. SimpleSamlPHP is serving as a SAML identity provider, fetching users in a local MySQL database.

My problem is that when requesting authentication against this IdP, Apache crashes throwing a "violation access" error, a.k.a. segfault. The problem is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138269/apache-error-notice-parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477-res) except that the child process exits with status 0 (but isn't this a Windows-specific feature of PHP regarding exit codes ?).

The common fix, copying libmysql.dll and php5apache2.dll in C:\Windows\system32, doesn't help.

Running VC++6 just-in-time debugger doesn't give me any information about which module is incriminated :'(

I tried to disable as much PHP extensions as I could. SimpleSamlPHP needs openSSL and PDO/MySQL, thus I kept only those 2 enabled, and crash happens anyway. I checked separately that using openSSL and MySQL works fine.

Finally I have to precise that the machine hosts 3 instances of PHP, including 2 in EasyPHP (2 separate installs), but only the concerned instance is active when the crash happens.

Any leads ?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Did you run php with apache's `mod_php`? I had the same situation here. It always crashes when a sp authentication comes in. I have no idea how this happened. But at the end, I avoided the problem by running php in FastCGI mode.