# Why does my XAMPP Apache service keep restarting?

Tags: apache, xampp, restart

For some reason my XAMPP Apache service keeps restarting. It started yesterday, but I can't really find the cause, because I have made many changes to my PC the day before (windows update, antivirus update, installed new programs, etc).

The XAMPP control panel says that it's running, but when I look at the processes in the windows task manager, I can see that it keeps restarting every second and the windows error reporting process keeps appearing too (without any dialog).

For some reason I can access the xampp first page (localhost or localhost/xampp), but nothing else (no phpmyadmin or anything else I put in htdocs). I have tried to reinstall XAMPP, and it's not the skype issue everyone knows about either. I have windows 8 pro.

The apache error.log keep repeating this:

```
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:21.237364 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 260:tid 572] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:21.298371 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:21.298371 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:21.298371 2013] [core:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00094: Command line: 'E:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d E:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:21.299372 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3060
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:23.213607 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 3060:tid 280] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:23.276605 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3060:tid 280] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:23.328611 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:24.584768 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 260:tid 572] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:24.649766 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:24.649766 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:24.649766 2013] [core:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00094: Command line: 'E:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d E:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:24.652768 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6620
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:26.551000 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 6620:tid 364] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:26.614999 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6620:tid 364] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:26.669006 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:27.826148 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 260:tid 572] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:27.886148 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:27.886148 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:27.886148 2013] [core:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00094: Command line: 'E:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d E:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:27.888150 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7032
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:29.761369 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 7032:tid 332] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:29.824377 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7032:tid 332] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Apr 04 00:21:29.876385 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 260:tid 572] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
```

My best guess is that I've got some kind of spyware with the apps I've installed.
Thank you very much for reading and any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED: 

NVIDIA FirstPacket was blocking it. I've disabled it and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED:

NVIDIA FirstPacket was blocking it. I've disabled it and it worked like a charm.