# AH00428: Parent: child process 3052 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting

Tags: php, apache

I'm using Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.8 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition. I am keep getting following error after installing above combination.

[Fri Aug 18 06:38:38.792287 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1344:tid 408] AH00428: Parent: child process 3052 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.......

[Fri Aug 18 06:55:11.944074 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1344:tid 408] AH00428: Parent: child process 984 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting......

These logs were not getting generated when i was using php5 but now its annoying while using php7 with apache 2.4.27.

I tried following solutions which i found from other questions/answers here but didn't helped: 
1. 
    ThreadStackSize 8888888

2. I copied the following two files from my PHP directory to the C:/windows/System32 directory and still getting errors: php5apache.dll, libmysql.dll.

Please help!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  Having the same issue.

Comment: Same issue here, please let me know if you found something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache error \[notice\] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138269/apache-error-notice-parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477-res)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

> This problem often happens in Windows because of smaller Apache’s
>   default stack size. And it usually happens when working with php code
>   that allocates a lot of stacks.
>
> To solve this issue, add the following at the end of apache config
>   file, httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8888888
</IfModule>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34452918/2592415

Comment: Thanks, Ivijan Stefan Stipić, but I tried this solution already which didn't help.

Comment: interesting. Do you find solution? This my solution solve problem on my side.

Comment: I wonder if 32-bit Apache needs to be half that (4194304)??

Comment: Hmm good point. I work on the 64bit version.